# Google Cloud SQL to external slave - can't get SSL working

Tags: mysql, ssl, cloud, slave

I've run into a problem. I have a Google Cloud SQL instance (Second Generation) and I use it as a master to run my own replication slave from. It all works fine, but I'm trying to change the connection to use SSL and failing. I have followed a variety of guides...

I've tried putting this in my.cnf

```
[client]
ssl-ca=server-ca.pem
ssl-cert=client-cert.pem
ssl-key=client-key.pem
```

I've also tried putting those lines under the *[mysqld]* heading. I've changed the slave to use SSL using

```
CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_SSL=1;
```

I've put the word *ssl* in my.cnf (this causes the connection to fail). I've also tried to change the slave using

```
CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_SSL=1, MASTER_SSL_CA = 'ca-cert.pem', MASTER_SSL_CERT = 'client-cert.pem', MASTER_SSL_KEY = 'client-key.pem';
```

Nothing will make it use SSL. If I query the slave is says SSL is disabled but putting *ssl* in the *[mysqld]* section stops replication working.

The certificates themselves are all downloaded from the instance and work fine in a PHP database class I use to connect from a different server.

Does anyone have any experience with this? I know it's failing as I've used tcpdump to watch the port and also *\s* in the MySQL console says SSL is off.

MySQL on the slave is version: 5.6.38-log MySQL Community Server (GPL).
On Google it reports MySQL 5.6

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, I hadn't installed mysql-devel, now working